# My Android Scrollview in a tabhost is consuming way too much memory

Tags: java, android, memory, scrollview, android-tabhost

I have an activity with a scrollview for some option checkboxes and buttons in a tabhost and whenever the the activity is being switched to in the tabhost for the first time my applications memory usage jumps by ~7 mb.

This puts me over the 16mb heap limit.

Is there a way to somehow reduce this massive memory consumption and to completely remove it whenever the user switches away from option tab to another tab ?

Comment: Android will take care of your memory and destroy paused `Activities` "in extreme low memory situations". Apparently this should be avoided. It's recommend to use `Views` instead of `Activities` as tab content. But this won't help in order to get rid of ~7mb memory. An activity containing _some_ buttons and checkboxes certainly can not take up ~7mb memory. Do you use large bitmaps (background, imagebutton etc.) or other ressources in your activity?

Comment: Hi, I am using only 1 small bitmap, 13 checkboxes, 6 buttons and a 4 textviews and that is it. It is rather large though and I think android is creating 1 large bitmap from the entire view to scroll it and that is taking up too much space. And I don't want to rely on android to handle that huge chunk of memory but would really like to do that myself when I think is the right time.

Comment: Yes exactly. You should not "force" the system in such situation. In addition the larger the memory the longer needs the GarbageCollector and your app feels sluggish. Because of that I wouldn't search a way to free the memory (activity)..I would search the reason why your activity takes up so much memory. You could remove the bitmap and see how that affects the heap usage

Comment: I did that and it appears that strangely enough that small bitmap does make alot of difference but unfiortunately not nearly enough. I stripped almost everything out of the scrollview except for the number of objects and it appears that android is simply managing memory badly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your TabActivity, try creating your Intents like this:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MyAwesomeTabView.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

This will ensure that whenever a user clicks on a tab, the clicked tab will be the only Activity that is on the heap (others will be destroyed).